# How to use multiple selectors when said selectors are stored in variables in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I tried this but it's not working:

```
var a = $('a');
var b = $('p');
var c = $('div');

$(a, b, c).hide();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors. You can select multiple independent sets of elements if you separate their selectors with commas:

```
$('a, p, div').hide();
```

If you already have fetched the different sets, you have the option of re-fetching them together (above), running [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) on each one, or merging the sets to run `.hide()` once:

```
a.add(b).add(c).hide();
```

For more information see the [`.add()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/add).

Comment: I know, I wanted to know how to do this if the html elements were stored inside variables. So if I remove the quotes it doesn't work. See my example.

Comment: Updated with information about merging element sets with `.add()`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
a.add(b).add(c).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, if you really do need to glue selection objects together, you can use [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
a.add(b).add(c).hide();
```

Just to add (haha)